# Error while importing Flickr api using Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, get, flickr

I'm trying to do a really simple Python webservice. It makes a 'photo.search' using the Flickr API and returns the titles and photos' url.

This webservice will be hosted on Google App Engine.

This is what I actually have right now :

```
import webapp2
from urllib import urlencode, urlopen
from xml.dom import minidom
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'

    data = _doget('flickr.photos.search', text='to_search', per_page='2')
    self.response.write('Ok')

  def _prepare_params(params):
    for (key, value) in params.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            params[key] = ','.join([item for item in value])
    return params

  def _doget(method, auth=False, **params):

    params = _prepare_params(params)
    url = 'http://flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=%s&method=%s&%s%s'% \
          ('stackoverflow_key', method, urlencode(params),
                  _get_auth_url_suffix(method, auth, params))

    result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
    minidom.parse(result.content)
    return result

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

I'm a beginner at Python, so I apologize if I did huge mistakes :) I tried several tutorials and sample codes that didn't work.

The imports are making a 500 server error

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

Does anyone can tell me what's wrong with it ?

If anyone have samples code that did the trick, could be nice.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time!! :D

***EDIT :***

All right, I changed my code, it's way simplier than before, for testing :

```
import webapp2
from urllib import urlencode, urlopen
from xml.dom import minidom
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import hashlib
import os


HOST = 'http://api.flickr.com'
API = '/services/rest'
API_KEY = 'my_key'


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

     def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'

        data = _doget('flickr.photos.search', auth=False, text='to_search', per_page='1')
        if data:
           self.response.write(data)
        else:
            self.response.write('Error')

 def _doget(method, **params):

    url = '%s%s/?api_key=%s&method=%s&%s&format=json'% \
      (HOST, API, API_KEY, method, urlencode(params))

    res = urlfetch.fetch(url).content

    # Flickr JSON api returns not valid JSON, which wrapped with "jsonFlickrApi(...)", so we get rid of it.
    if 'jsonFlickrApi(' in res:
        return res[14:-1]

    return json.loads(res)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

When I copy/paste this url, it works perfectly. My aim is to return the data as flickr returns it. But still not working. The print isn't even shown :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first glance your app has several issues:

1. I suppose HOST should be 'http://api.flickr.com'
2. Indentation and formatting (: after if and else) in if-else statement in MainPage class
3. Undefined varibale "photos" in self.response.write(photos)
4. Undefined functions "_prepare_params", "_get_auth_url_suffix", "_get_data" and variable "debug" in _doget function.
5. You should call read() method of urlopen result
6. You should use minidom.parseString
7. You can use run_wsgi_app to run your app

So here is the working example:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import webapp2
from urllib import urlencode, urlopen
from xml.dom import minidom
import hashlib
import os

HOST = 'http://api.flickr.com'
API = '/services/rest'
API_KEY = 'my_key'

debug = False

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'

        data = _doget('flickr.photos.search', auth=False, text='boston', per_page='2')

        if data:
            photos = data.getElementsByTagName("photo")
            for photo in photos:
                farm_id = 1 # ???
                server_id = photo.attributes['server'].value
                photo_id = photo.attributes['id'].value
                secret = photo.attributes['secret'].value
                photo_url = 'http://farm{farm_id}.staticflickr.com/{server_id}/{photo_id}_{secret}.jpg'.format(farm_id=farm_id,                                                                                                         server_id=server_id,                                                                                                         photo_id=photo_id,                                                                                                         secret=secret)
                self.response.write('<img src="{0}">'.format(photo_url))
        else:
            self.response.write('Error')


def _doget(method, auth=False, **params):
    #print "***** do get %s" % method

    params = params
    url = '%s%s/?api_key=%s&method=%s&%s'% \
      (HOST, API, API_KEY, method, urlencode(params))

    #another useful debug print statement
    if debug:
        print "_doget", url

    res = urlopen(url)
    res = res.read()

    return minidom.parseString(res)


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To format flickr photo url I used http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html, but I havent found where to get farm_id parameter, I hope you'll manage it by yourself )

---

Furthermore, it can be easier to use json format by passing 'format=json' to the API request URL and a bit more properly to use GAE urlfetch service:

```
import json
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

# ...

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # ...
        for photo in data['photos']['photo']:
            farm_id = 1 # ???
            server_id = photo['server']
            photo_id = photo['id']
            secret = photo['secret']
            # ...

def _doget(method, auth=False, **params):
    # ...
    url = '%s%s/?api_key=%s&method=%s&%s&format=json'% \
      (HOST, API, API_KEY, method, urlencode(params))

    res = urlfetch.fetch(url).content

    # Flickr JSON api returns not valid JSON, which wrapped with "jsonFlickrApi(...)", so we get rid of it.
    if 'jsonFlickrApi(' in res:
        return res[14:-1]

    return json.loads(res)
```

Comment: Is there a way to debug it ? Because I'm not skilled enought to know where my errors are =/

Comment: Hmm, at first you should try to be more careful and not to make syntax mistakes ) You can use IDE syntax error highlighting or similar tools. Then your best friends in debugging should become IDE console, logging module and just "print".

Comment: I just update my post and paste my "new code", way simpler for debugging, but still not working and my print test is not shown =/

Comment: Please try my example and then compare with your one.

Comment: I did try it. I almost have all of your lines, except

if data:
   self.response.write(data)
else:
   self.response.write('Error').

Look at the "edit" part of my post, I got your code :(

Comment: So, lets check your app.yaml file, could you include it too?

Comment: application: my_hidden_app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: testflickr.application

Comment: your app.yaml seems to be ok. But it seems like you've forgot to import urlfetch and json modules. Also, you should change content-type to text/plain if you want to see JSON.

Comment: All right I just tried something : data = _doget('Hello'), and the _doget directy return 'Hello'. If I self.response.write(data), it's not working.. Any ideas??

Comment: I think there is something wrong when I call _doget(), because If a try to call it, return nothing, and self.response.write('ok'), the OK isn't shown

Comment: I did resolved my problem by putting _doget() function outside of class MainPage.. That's all. But thanks a lot for your help and your time !! I valid your answer!

Comment: I've noticed that this function has slightly different indentation, but thought it just SO formatting issue. But, you could leave it in class, add `self` as the first argument and call it as self._doget() from get method. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Where does `_get_data` get imported?

On a side note, appengine, comes with a urlfetch service that I would recommend you use unless you have a very good reason not too. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/

In usage this would look something like:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url)
if result.status_code == 200:
    minidom.parse(result.content)
```

Comment: All right I changed it, thank you :) Do you see anything wrong with my _doget function ? Because when I call it, my 'Ok' statement is not shown anymore